# Change org mode's heading font size (like logseq) in respect of properties

Tags: org-mode, fonts, font-lock, text-properties

I want my org file can be used in Emacs and `logseq` interchangeably (in pc Emacs, in mobile `logseq`)

What I want is like `logseq` to have other properties for the heading text, like

```
:PROPERTIES:
:heading: 1
:END:
```

and use the value of heading to determine the size of that heading text displayed in Emacs.
Also when heading text contains code snippet, I want it to have same enlarge size.

In org mode I know I can enlarge the font face of eg. `org-level-1`, however I usually use `org-level-1` as my TODO, and I don't want it being so large, and this doesn't change code snippet either.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. In particular, I have no idea what `logseq` is, so It might help to explain that and how it can use Org mode files.

Comment: Can safely ignore the `logseq` part. I want org mode to display text size according to the `:heading:` properties, say `:heading: 1` is largest, `:heading: 2` a bit smaller and so on. And also it applied to code snippet. If no `:heading:` is specified, use default font size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be possible to change the heading fonts via properties, but you can probably get what you want easier using more standard methods.

Why don't use the org-todo face for TODO and the org-level-n faces for headings? You can use `C-u M-x what-cursor-position RET` to find the face of the character under the cursor (it will be listed under "There are text properties here:"). (Try it to get the face of the code snippet you want to change.) Once you know the right face you can use `set-face-attribute` to change it. To apply your changes automatically in org-mode buffers, add them to org-mode-hook in your init.el file:

```lisp
(defun my-org-faces ()
    (set-face-attribute 'org-todo nil :height 0.8)
    (set-face-attribute 'org-level-1 nil :height 1.2)
    (set-face-attribute 'org-level-2 nil :height 1.1))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'my-org-faces)
```

If you just use the above and don't set org-code height explicitly, org-code fragments in headings will inherit the height property from the org-level-x font, so they will be the same size as surrounding text.

Comment: Thanks, your answer actually helped me improve my org mode looking. However I still can not get code snippet on heeding the same size as normal heading. It seems to me that ```org-code``` just apply to the whole buffer and doesn't adapt with ```org-level-*```?

Comment: I added an edit below the code in my response. Does that help?

Comment: It works! Thanks!